# Magento : Location Of Images

Tags: magento-1.9, image

Does small images and all other resolution of all images, Magento create only in cache folder ? I tried to find in FTP but I found only original of img that I downloaded to admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am considering that you are talking about products' images.

Magento saves those images in following format and place:

> [Magento Root Folder]/media/catalog/product/[fisrt letter of image name]/[second letter of image name]/[image name].[image extension]

For example: If image name is abcd.jpg, then it would be saved in:

> [Magento Root Folder]/media/catalog/product/a/b/abcd.jpg

Comment: I mean where is products images like "example_150x150.png" i know where to find original photos. (magento 2.1)